# Ternary Operator with two conditions

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I am currently working on a ternary operator that I want to have 2 conditions. I am having issues with the second condition. I am trying to get it to where `If ActionTypeId = 0 OR ActionCompletedByID` is greater than 0 display null. If true, return the `StatusModal`.I believe the way I have it written is in the situation of AND and not OR is there a way to write these conditions as an OR?

```
 currentNurse.ActionTypeID === 0, currentNurse.ActionCompletedByID > 0? null :
     <StatusModal
      details = {details}>
     </StatusModal>
```

Comment: `||` is your friend. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could inverse the checks and take logical AND along with the wanted tags - and omit `null`.

```
currentNurse.ActionTypeID !== 0 && currentNurse.ActionCompletedByID <= 0 && 
    <StatusModal
      details = {details}>
    </StatusModal>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you've written it is neither AND or OR. I don't think what you have is even valid syntax.

What you need to do is use the OR operator.

```
 currentNurse.ActionTypeID === 0 || currentNurse.ActionCompletedByID > 0? null :
     <StatusModal
      details = {details}>
     </StatusModal>
```